# Append column to matrix, using Eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen

It's quite a simple task, but I was not able to find an answer to it:

Using the Eigen library, suppose I have `Matrix2Xd mat` and `Vector2d vec`, where

```
mat = 1 1 1
      1 1 1
vec = 2 2
```

Now I need something like `mat.addCol(vec)` such that afterwards

```
mat = 1 1 1 2
      1 1 1 2
```

What is the best (simplest) way to accomplish this?

Please note, that this is not a duplicate of [How do you make a matrix out of vectors in eigen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470893/how-do-you-make-a-matrix-out-of-vectors-in-eigen). I don't want to initialy construct the matrix but append to an existing one. Or is there maybe a trick, how to use the comma initialization in this case? The following code will fail:

```
Matrix2Xd mat(2,3);
Vector2d vec;
mat << 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
vec << 2, 2;

cout << mat << endl;
mat << vec;             // <-- crashes here
cout << mat << endl;
```

---

**Edit:** The following works, but I don't like the need of a temporary variable for such a basic task. Is there a better way?

```
Matrix2Xd tmp(2, mat.cols()+1);
tmp << mat, vec;
mat = tmp;
```

Comment: You did read the first answer in the dupe: "The matrix m mus have been properly resized first."? An Eigen Matrix has a [`resize`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#afbbb33d14fe7fb9683019a39ce1c659d) member function... Documentation can be googled, or read, at the least.

Comment: @rubenvb `resize` does not keep the content of the matrix. If I do `mat.resize(2, mat.cols()+1);`, the matrix is filled with some random values afterwards.

Comment: Then you'll need to either create a temporary or initialize it to the correct size.

Comment: @rubenvb The size is not known in the beginning, so this is not possible. I hoped there is a better solution than copying all the data to a temporary :/

Comment: There is no data structure (that is contiguous in memory, as would be wanted for a numerical matrix) that fullfills your needs. What sizes are we talking about?

Comment: @rubenvb Well, for example the matrix class of the Armadillo library has `insert_cols()` and `insert_rows()`, so I hoped there is something similar in Eigen. But I'm happy with ggaels answer, so I think we can end this discussion.

Comment: just so you know, those functions might well reallocate the memory, you're just "hiding" that fact from plain view. See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24186398/256138) for some more info.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `conservativeResize` for that purpose:

```
mat.conservativeResize(mat.rows(), mat.cols()+1);
mat.col(mat.cols()-1) = vec;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I figured out that it is even possible to write `mat.conservativeResize(NoChange, mat.cols()+1);` which lets the number of rows unchanged.

Comment: Is this approach recommended from a performance perspective? 

As I understand, conservativeResize() will allocate memory again and copy old data to the new location. Suppose we need to append multiple vectors to the matrix, does this method suffer from performance loss significantly?