# How to pre-allocate memory for a growing Eigen::MatrixXd

Tags: c++, memory, eigen

I have a growing database in form of an `Eigen::MatrixXd`. My matrix starts empty and gets rows added one by one until it reaches a maximum predefined (known at compile time) number of rows.

At the moment I grow it like that (from the Eigen docs and many posts here and elsewhere):

```
MatrixXd new_database(database.rows()+1, database.cols());
new_database << database, new_row;
database = new_database;
```

But this seems way more inefficient than it needs to be, since it makes a lot of useless memory reallocation and data copying every time a new row is added... Seems like I should be able to pre-allocate a bunch of memory of size `MAX_ROWS*N_COLS` and let the matrix grow in it, however I can't find an equivalent of `std::vector`'s `capacity` with Eigen.

Note: I may need to use the matrix at anytime before it is actually full. So I do need a distinction between what would be its `size` and what would be its `capacity`.

How can I do this?

EDIT 1: I see there is a `MaxSizeAtCompileTime` but I find the doc rather unclear with no examples. Anyone knows if this is the way to go, how to use this parameter and how it would interact with the `resize` and `conservativeResize`?

EDIT 2: [C++: Eigen conservativeResize too expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186398/c-eigen-conservativeresize-too-expensive) provides another interesting approach while raising question regarding non contiguous data... Anyone has some good insight on that matter?

Comment: why not use std::vector?

Comment: because I'm doing matrix multiplication. I have thought of using a `std::vector` of `Eigen::Vector`, but I assume multiplying an `Eigen::Matrix` with an `Eigen::Vector` would be optimized and more efficient than taking several dot products of a `Eigen::Vector`'s in a for loop to then fill a new `Eigen::Vector` with the results...

Comment: The docs mention a conservativeResize function that preserves the values of the matrix.  At the very least it will save you from coding the resize as you've been doing.  Not sure if it has better performance though.

Comment: That's on line of code saved, yeah! From what I understand conservativeResize follows exactly the same inefficient process of memory reallocation and data copying when the size increases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I want to mention before I forget, is that you may want to consider using a row major matrix for storage.

The simplest (and probably best) solution to your question would be to use [block operations](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) to access the top rows.

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

int main(void)
{
    const int rows = 5;
    const int cols = 6;

    MatrixXd database(rows, cols);
    database.setConstant(-1.0);

    std::cout << database << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        database.row(i) = VectorXd::Constant(cols, i);

        // Use block operations instead of the full matrix
        std::cout << database.topRows(i+1) << "\n\n";

    }

    std::cout << database << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of just printing the matrix, you could do whatever operations you require.

Comment: To complete the answer, to avoid repeating `.topRows()` every time, you can wrap it using either c++ `auto`, or in c++98, declare: `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd> db = database.topRows(i+1)`, and use db as a regular `Eigen::Matrix`.